# Entity framework step issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to figure out someone else code.... 
what this does is taking the username and password from the user and checks from the database table whether username and password is correct.... 
his DataLayer looks like this:

```
public class UserRepository : IUser
    {
        Context con = new Context();
        public UserDTO GetUser(string user)
        {
            User u = con.Users.Find(user);
            UserDTO User = new UserDTO();
            if (u != null)
            {
                User.Username = u.UserName;
                User.Password = u.Password;            
            }
            return User;
        }
    }
```

IUser interface:

```
    public interface IUser
        {
            UserDTO GetUser(string user);
        }
```

ServiceLayer looks like this:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        IUser data;

        public UserService(IUser data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public bool Authenticate(string user,string pwd)
        {
            UserDTO u = data.GetUser(user);
            if (u.Username == user && u.Password == pwd)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

IuserService Interface:

```
 public interface IUserService
    {
        bool Authenticate(string user, string pwd);
    }
```

And the MVC Controller Looks like this:

```
     public class HomeController : Controller
    {                          
        public ActionResult Log()
        {    
            return View();
        }          

        IUserService ser;
        public HomeController()
        {
            ser = new UserService(new UserRepository());
        }
        public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (ser.Authenticate(user.UserName, user.Password))
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Success";
            }
            else
                ViewBag.Message = "UnSuccess";

            return View();
        }
```

I can't really understand what he has done in this Controller Constructor (ser = new UserService(new UserRepository())) but the code works perfectly ....
What is he trying to do, is he trying to Connect this controller into the DataLayer(UserRepository class)?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The home controller has a Login Action method which accepts a user model, which has a username and password.

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
```

The action method uses the user service to try to authenticate the user's password. 
The controller calls the UserService's Authenticate method which takes in the supplied username and password.

```
if (ser.Authenticate(user.UserName, user.Password))
```

The service calls the UserRepositories GetUser method, which tries to find a user by the username.

```
public bool Authenticate(string user,string pwd)
{
    UserDTO u = data.GetUser(user);
```

...

```
User u = con.Users.Find(user);
```

If it finds a user by that username in the db, it check returns the user object with the username and password.

```
        if (u != null)
        {
            User.Username = u.UserName;
            User.Password = u.Password;            
        }
        return User;
```

The rest of the authenticate method checks if this UserDTO's password matches with the initial password supplied to the Login Action method, and returns true or false depending on that.

```
        if (u.Username == user && u.Password == pwd)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

Comment: yes.. can you please explain me why he has put this code in his constructor:...ser = new UserService(new UserRepository());

Comment: is he trying to Connect this controller into the DataLayer(UserRepository class)?

Comment: @Dayan - They wanted to create a UserService object when the Controller is instantiated. It is a way of connecting to the data layer, yes. The UserRepository just does CRUD operations on users, but the UserService takes care of business logic or other things like authenticating. I am not sure why UserRepo is passed into the UserService's constructor by the controller though.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there is no hashing of the password prior to looking up the matching user. This means that you have inherited a database with unencrypted passwords, which is very poor for security. I would recommend updating the code to check the hashed password and hashing the passwords already in the database. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right

Comment: Also, the passing in of the UserRepo into the UserService sounds like constructor injection to me. There is an overview of dependency injection here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254091/Implementing-Microsoft-Unity-Design-Pattern